# Linker error LNK2005/1169 when using smart pointer C++

Tags: c++, class, linker-errors

So I'm separating class definition and implementation.

- Platform: Windows x64
- Compiler: MSVC
- IDE: VS 2022

Error "resolves" when I use **inline** keyword before smart pointer, but I want to understand the problem-

Error codes:

```
"class std::unique_ptr<class Window,struct std::default_delete<class Window> > loaderWindow" (?loaderWindow@@3V?$unique_ptr@VWindow@@U?$default_delete@VWindow@@@std@@@std@@A) already defined"
```

Removed all code unrelated to error.

Header file:

```
#pragma once

class Window {
public:
    Window() noexcept;
};

auto loaderWindow = std::make_unique<Window>();
```

Source file:

```
Window::Window() noexcept
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Ctor called", L"OK", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Putting global variables in headers is always a problematic thing. And combining global variable declaration with initialization in a header file even more so

Comment: Look closely at the error message. `..loaderWindow .... already defined`. This is because you define the global variable `loaderWindow` in your header file `#pragma once` doesn't help here. The only thing you can do is not declaring global variables in your header files.

Comment: BTW: you removed too much code, so the error cannot be reproduced without doing some guesswork.

Comment: The code hasn't completely separated the class definition from its implementation. `auto loaderWindow = std::make_unique<Window>();` is implementation (although not part of the class itself), not class definition. Move it into the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include your header file in more than one source files. This is why you see this error message. Remove the definition of the global variable from your header file, or include it in one source file only.

Comment: Move the definition. Don't rely on only including the header in one source file; that's a bug waiting to happen. +1.